# Typescript Record and tuples unable to assign it

Tags: typescript

Why can't I assign the data to a record? [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=60&pln=2&pc=1#code/FDAEoFwTwBwU1AWSgJTgYwPYCcAmoBeUNLPAHgEYAfAJgBpQBtAZwmwEsA7Acwc4FcAtgCM42ALoA%20UAG4Q4LJ1agAVs0ydCoAN6gKALiYAiI3QriGNQ4xN0a4gL5ywoRcub90cZs0NJUGDj4RLqgAPRhoADuOADWzC7gBsam5nSJoFYpduIuDi5uEKAAZgCG7AA2hsgkQVpqGjLhkWLYOC4RoAAqsAgA5LrJABSsHDygVKACImIAlIziTVkjbFzcE1NCotjzi6AOfaDszFOYRaU%207NycpcIVCBCYkL2gfTWBeH0AdB2RPfAnTDFUAwNrwbDQV4UQ6lbAILhYQQwUoQdh3OA-cCdf79FZjdaTabbXaHY6nc6Xa63e6QJ7QeCvFirHh8LZicTfX7dWHcOBFOEAR347DhJxooDg90EcE4EBGs1Awn4RXU-GwXlAglKUFAAAtSgA3BDFOBRMQ-IA)

```
type MyRecord = Record<1|2, [string, number]> ;

  const json = { 1: ["",1], 2: ["",2]};

  const sucess:  MyRecord = {  // works
    1: ["",1],
    2: ["",2]
  }
  const fail: MyRecord = json; // error
  // Type '{ 1: (string | number)[]; 2: (string | number)[]; }' is not assignable to type 'MyRecord'.
  // Types of property '1' are incompatible.
  // Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type '[string, number]'.
  // Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer
```

Comment: Because the type of `json` is inferred to be `{1: (string | number)[], 2: (string | number)[]}`, and `(string | number)[]` is not a tuple type. The compiler won't generally infer tuple types for array literals unless it's in some *context* to suggest that, and `const json = {...}` has no such context. Only *later* do you try to assign to `fail`, and at that point it's too late. All the compiler can do then is warn you; if you want a different type for `json` you should go back and annotate it.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a variable with an initializer, TypeScript has to *infer* the type of that variable from its initializer.  And there are many possible types that are compatible with any given initializer.  For example, given:

```
const json = { 1: ["", 1], 2: ["", 2] };
```

The following types would all be compatible:

```
const json1: MyRecord = { 1: ["", 1], 2: ["", 2] };
const json2: unknown = { 1: ["", 1], 2: ["", 2] };
const json3: Record<number, any> = { 1: ["", 1], 2: ["", 2] };
const json4: { 1: any[], 2: ["", 2] } = { 1: ["", 1], 2: ["", 2] };
const json5: MyRecord | string = { 1: ["", 1], 2: ["", 2] };
```

The compiler has to pick one.  How?  It uses *heuristics* that are appropriate for a wide range of uses.  In this case it turns out to be:

```
/* const json: {
    1: (string | number)[];
    2: (string | number)[];
} */
```

You can see that the array literal `["", 1]` is inferred as having type `(string | number)[]`, an unordered mutable array of arbitrary length where each element can be a string or a number.  If you wanted to modify the array like `json[1][2] = 3`, you'd be happy with that.

But unfortunately you wanted to *later* use `json` as a `MyRecord`.  And since the type of `json` is not assignable to that, it fails.  The compiler doesn't take future uses into account when inferring types for variables.  (Try to imagine how poorly a compiler that did do this would perform.)  Any information more specific than `{1: (string | number)[]; 2: (string | number)[]}` which the compiler had about the initializer to `json` has been thrown away already.

---

On the other hand, when you write this:

```
const success: MyRecord = { 1: ["", 1], 2: ["", 2] };
```

(same as `json1` above) it works.  That's because the compiler doesn't need to *infer* the type for the variable anymore.  It just has to check the initializer against the type.  And so it checks the initializer against `MyRecord` and sees that it satisfies the definition.  In other words, this works because it is using the variable type to analyze the initializer, as opposed to using the initializer to analyze the variable.

[Playground lik to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIFlwCVoGMD2AnAJrAvLChjgDwCMsAPrAEwA0sA2gM6iYCWAdgOYOcCuAWwBG0TAF0AfAG4QGTq1gArZuk75YAb1hkAXEwBEBhmXEMa+xkfPjYAX1kB6AFSx5ilWv2bgsPzv0AClYOHipYARExAEpGcVl-WiCQrm5wyNFMWPjgO1hnRzk1D1VOPQRkNCxcAm1yq2MdMyTDRppbB2B3UGVSi1h+TgBrTnQAd3VagNaTZv6Gm3tZbt61AGZ9ImqSDLEGAENOcEkNOstrJvNzto7l4p7PTgAWb2nD8DirmdoO0+mFy4tAHtJZde6rTgAVn0iC2OHCKTCU3qF1MX2BtxAYIUPWY-FQ0GYzBhlWINS0fkcjlgYywQ2Yvn+qLMjPmF3auWxigAZvt2AAbElw8mPaSwKmwMSYLCMiUAFSgcAA5GdYME2Kl0kJMtkxf11aE0tRdlk4mK7ErYOxmBF0D19kT2NxOPthPy4KB0LAIDBYErYVUcEqAHSy6kKmA29Dc2CQaUwTAQP1kS37TBwLgYQSQfagdhu6ChynhxV+g2a43amJxS3W232x3O13u71en3Klganh8KsSENh2BytPcaA9dMAR347HTNpokvdgmgnFAwWisGE-Fx6H4mAJsEE+3AsAAFvsAG5wbnQMZiUNAA)